# Part of regular expression should not be matching . or , in the end

Tags: php, regex, text

I want to extract value amounts from documents which are present in textual form using regular expressions. Very often the text starts with some blanks, some comma, semikolon and than a value, e.g.

```
   -.          .-       12.345
```

or

```
                        123.45
```

or (and here comes the problem - A figure starting with just a . meaning 0.45

```
                        .45
```

I use the following regular expression to match the whitespaces

```
(?<seperator>(?:[^\S]|[.:,-\/—;_])*)
```

and the following to match the value amounts:

```
(?<value>((([+|-|.]*(\$|\%|(C\$)|(\€))*(?:\d+[.,']*\d*[.,']{0,1})+[?:mkC\%\€\$\£]*([?:mkC\%\€\$\£]|C\$)*))?))
```

By combining both, I can extract the seperator as well as the value seperately. How can I create a regular expression, so that the seperator regex does not accept a . or , in the end and that the . or , can be added to the value matching group by accepting an optional ([.,]?) in the beginning.

I posted the regular expression for evaluation here. I am using the regular expressions from Java and this works just fine. https://regex101.com/r/eF5bW3/3

I had a look at lookbehind but it didn't seem to be working for me. The value should be .45 and not 45:

[image: Value should be .45 and not 45]

Comment: What is the "separator" for input " ---,,,... 1.123"?

Comment: do you really want to ignore values such `.` or `,` at the end?  maybe try a simpler regexp to match any sequence containing numbers delimited by whitespace.  try to parse it and if an exception occurs, maybe just skip that one or log it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex. It does what you want to do:

```
[\s,.-]*(?<!\.)((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\.\d+))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xO1cO4/1)

by the way you mentioned comma in your question but it isn't there in the examples shown but I included it in answer, anyway the idea here is use negative lookbehind to make sure there that the `*` doesn't consume the `.` before the number you want to match. If you goal is to match the only number in every line, use a simpler regex as follows, It also matches what you want:

```
(\d*?.?\d+)
```

[SIMPLER REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vD1gF8/1)

**EDIT 1**

To handle cases like `..45` as you mentioned , you can use the following regex:

```
[\s,.-]*(\d*(?=\.)(?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\.\d+)))
```

[EDIT 1 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jP3sY3/1)

Comment: Great! Is there a way to expand this, not to match a single "."?
[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xO1cO4/2)
`..45` should not match 5 but .45?

Comment: @MarcGiombetti , lemme check Marc

Comment: @MarcGiombetti , I've updated the answer, check it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something similar to your regex(matching onther characters which ocours in your regex), but to match only numerical value, with optional point, try with:

```
(?<value>[+-]?([$%C$€]|C$)*(?:\d*\.?\d+)([mkC%€$£]|C\$)*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vD1gF8/2)

if you want to match `<separator>` also, you can use:

```
(?<seperator>(?:[-\s.:,\/—;_])*?)(?<value>[+-]?([$%C$€]|C$)*(?:\d*\.?\d+)(?:[mkC%€$£]|C\$)*)
```